# i was trying to add gripper to a existing moveit package

Tags: python, ros

I was trying to perform a pick and place operation with techman robot. https://github.com/TechmanRobotInc/tm.... The techman robot for ros melodic version does not provide gripper and camera. So how can I add a sensor and grippesr to it.

Sorry, I am very new to ros and moveit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to add the gripper and robot together on the MoveIt, I think the easiest way is using MoveIt Setup Assistant to do it.

http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html

Inside Techman Robot ROS, it provided robot model(tm5-700, tm5-900 and tm12 1300 type), so you can get the robot model. The only thing is you need to do is add your camera model and gripper model.

By the way, MoveIt is a  planning the robot trajectory, it doesn't matter about the other sensors.

Comment: yaa but how can i add gripper . do I need to design a gripper in cad and converts into urdf and add to it .

Comment: Inside the setup assistant tutorial, there is a step to tell you how to add a gripper.
Indeed, you need to design a gripper in cad and converts into URDF and add to it.
But I think you can ask to gripper's company to ask them to give you gripper CAD.